# SaveChanges doesn't work with ADO.NET Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using ADO.NET Entity Framework data model for my ASP.NET MVC project. I am trying to insert into multiple tables and called .SaveChanges() method. It doesn't throw any exception and doesn't insert into these tables.

What could be wrong here?

```
Object1 obj1 = new  Object1();
obj1.TID = 300; //Auto generated but I am assigning the value. 
obj1.TypeID = 1;

Object2 obj2 = new Object2();

obj2.TID = 300;
obj2.StartDT = DateTime.Now;

db.AddToObject1(obj1);
db.AddToObject2(obj2);

db.SaveChanges();
db.AcceptAllChanges();
```

Comment: what is the state of the entity.. use ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager

Comment: This *should* work - how are you connecting to your database?? Is it a "user instance" of SQL Server by any chance? Can you show us your connection string, please??

Comment: Also, I am unsure about the `.AcceptAllChanges()` at the end; `.SaveChanges();` should be sufficient. Does commenting out this line make any difference??

Comment: I tried by commenting .AcceptAllChanges() method. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try save changes for each object like:

```
db.AddToObject1(obj1);
db.SaveChanges();

db.AddToObject2(obj2);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I have tried but I received an error message this time. The second insert statement failed. I received Foreign Constraint error.

Comment: Hi, I think if the Foreign Constraint error occurs, it doesn't have anything to do with the entity framework, check your database and post your problem if it still remains unfixed...cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You first have to add the object to the context and then modify their properties:

```
Object1 obj1 = new Object1();
Object2 obj2 = new Object2();
db.AddToObject1(obj1);
db.AddToObject2(obj2);


obj1.TID = 300; //Auto generated but I am assigning the value. 
obj1.TypeID = 1;


obj2.TID = 300;
obj2.StartDT = DateTime.Now;


db.SaveChanges();
```